# "Land der Dichter und Denker" als Synonym für Deutschland

Tags: synonym

Während des Wahlkampfes bin ich schon mehrmals auf diese Wendung gestoßen. Zum Beispiel:

> Zum Land der Dichter und Denker passt eine Politik, die in Ideen investiert.

Lässt sich dieser Ausdruck als "volles" Synonym von Deutschland wie z.B "Bundesrepublik" verwenden oder schwingt bei ihm ein anderes Gefühl (Spott, Ironie, Lob usw.) mit bzw. ist die Wendung umgangssprachlich?

Comment: Wer dieses Synonym verwendet, möchte auf die kulturelle (Goethe, Schiller, Bach) und wissenschaftshistorische (Benz, Daimler, Siemens, Gauss, Koch) Vergangenheit Deutschlands hinweisen.

Comment: "Bundesland" ist kein Synonym zu "Deutschland" (sondern die Bezeichnung seiner föderalen Teilstaaten), was du meinst ist "(die) Bundesrepublik" ;)

Comment: @Annatar: Der Begriff »Bundesland« ist zweideutig. Damit kann einerseits ein Land gemeint sein, das Teil eines Länderbundes ist (z.B. Kärnten oder Sachsen), es kann aber auch der gesamte Länderverbund gemeint sein (z.B. Mexiko oder die Schweiz). Offiziell heißen die Teile in der Schweiz »Kantone« und in D und Ö »Länder«. Das Ganze heißt sowohl in D als auch in Ö »Bund«. Der Begriff »Bundesland« ist weder in D noch in Ö eine offizielle Bezeichnung.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Sicher, dass "Bundesland" keine offizielle Bezeichnung ist? Es wird doch in Deutschland sonst an so gut wie jede staatliche Organisation ein "Bundes-" geklebt (Bundestag, Bundespräsident, usw.). In jedem Fall ist es kein Synonym zu "Deutschland" insgesamt, und das war ja der Punkt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Und ich würde einfach mal behaupten, dass man in Deutschland so gut wie nie "Bundesland" zur Schweiz sagen würde. Allein schon, weil das von unseren werten Schweizer Nachbarn leicht als abschätzig missverstanden werden könnte. Vielleicht ist das in Österreich anders.

Comment: @Annatar: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliedstaat#Bezeichnungen zweiter Absatz in diesem Abschnitt: *»In der Schweizerischen Eidgenossenschaft heißen die Gliedstaaten Kantone, in Österreich Länder ebenso wie in Deutschland. In den beiden letztgenannten Staaten ist allerdings die inoffizielle, synonyme Bezeichnung „Bundesländer“ weit verbreitet.«*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Interessant, wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das Gebilde, das die Bundesländer unter einem Dach vereinigt, heißt *Bundesstaat* - Außer in den USA und z.B. in der Geschichte Deutschlands die Staaten, die den *Deutschen Bund* ausgemacht haben, als sie noch welche waren.

Comment: @tofro: "Außer in den USA" ... und in Mexiko. Man könnte das eventuell auf Staaten verallgemeinern, die sich in ihrer offiziellen Bezeichnung "Vereinigte Staaten von XYZ" nennen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wenn ich die Frage richtig verstehe, möchtest du wissen, ob man *Land der Dichter und Denker* in ähnlicher Weise für *Deutschland* verwenden kann wie *die Bundesrepublik* (oft zu hören als: *Buntsreblik*) oder *die BRD*.

Dies wäre dann ein "volles Synonym" in dem Sinne, dass mit der Variation des Wortes keine Variation der intendierten Bedeutung einhergeht. So sagen Politiker und (leider auch) Journalisten oft "der Freistaat", wenn sie Bayern meinen, oder - dies nun nur Journalisten - "das Grautier", wenn sie einen Esel meinen.

Antwort auf Deine Frage: Nein, *Land der Dichter und Denker* ist kein "volles Synonym" in diesem Sinne. Es trägt immer eine zusätzliche Bedeutungsfracht, die in reinen Landesbezeichnungen wie *Deutschland*, *die Bundesrepublik*, und *die BRD* nicht enthalten ist. Diese Zusatzbedeutung kann entweder positiv und lobend gemeint sein (wie in deinem Beispiel) oder auch ironisch, sarkastisch, etc.  Hier kommt es wie immer auf den Kontext an. In dem Beispiel aus der Frage ist Ironie sicherlich nicht intendiert. "Im Land der Dichter und Denker regiert der ökologische Unverstand" wäre dagegen sarkastisch.

Es gibt zu "Land der Dichter und Denker" auch populäre Parodisierungen:

> Land der Richter und Henker

(häufig) oder

> Land des Gelichters und der Bänker

(selten).

**Nach Kommentaren:** *Land der Dichter und Denker* (LDD) sollte sich - wenn mit Bedacht und kulturhistorischem Gespür verwandt - überhaupt nicht auf ein staatliches Gebilde beziehen sondern vielmehr auf einen Kulturraum, hier nämlich den deutschsprachigen. Insofern ist *LDD* eigentlich überhaupt kein Synonym für *Deutschland*. Umgekehrt ist aber das, was heute *Deutschland* heißt, Teil des LDD.

Comment: Wer solche Phrasen benutzt, sollte auch ein wenig mitdenken. Vor einigen Jahren hat z.B. Thomas Gottschalk eine Sendung moderiert, in der Kandidaten aus Deutschland, Österreich und der Schweiz gegeneinander antraten. Gottschalk sagte zu Beginn der Sendung auch etwas über die Länder. Er sagte: »Deutschland, das Land der Dichter und Denker. - Österreich, das Land aus dem Schlagobers und Sachertorte kommen.« Das haben ihm damals viele Österreicher übel genommen, weil diese beiden Aussagen zusammen bedeuten: »Österreich hat keine Dichter und Denker hervorgebracht«, was schlichtweg falsch ist.

Comment: Und umgekehrt gibt es die  Schwarzwälder Kirschtorte. - Aber, um zum Ernst zurückzukehren: Ich denke "Land der Dichter und Denker" bezieht sich - wenn mit Bedacht verwandt - überhaupt nicht auf ein staatliches Gebilde sondern vielmehr auf einen Kulturraum, hier nämlich den deutschsprachigen, insofern wären Wien, Graz, Klagenfurt und der Strudengau schon mitgedacht.

Comment: *Buntsreblik* habe ich noch nie gehört. Ich nehme an das dass eine regionale Eigenart ist. Es wäre zu begrüßen, wenn du das in deiner Antwort erwähnen würdest.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Wenn man explizit von einem »Land« spricht, kann der Sprecher meinen was er will, aber der Empfänger der Botschaft wird in den meisten Fällen »Land« verstehen, nicht »Kulturraum«. Vor Gottschalks Fettnäpfchentritt wäre mir übrigens gar nicht in den Sinn gekommen, den Begriff *Land der Dichter und Denker* mit Deutschland in Verbindung zu bringen. Ich dachte bis dahin, dass sich das auf jedes Land anwenden ließe, das Dichter und Denker hervorgebracht hat: »Japan ist ein Land der Dichter und Denker.«